# Variable strangely takes the value zero after the call of a subroutine

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran-common-block

I have been facing some issues trying to convert a code previously compiled with compaq visual fortran 6.6 to gfortran.
Here is a specific problem I have met with gfortran :
There is a variable called "et" which takes the value 3E+10. Then the program calls a subroutine. "et" doesn't appear in the subroutine, but after coming back to the main program it has now the value 0.
When compliling with compaq visual fortran I didn't have this problem.
The code I am working on is a huge scientific program, so I put below only a small part of it :

```
c
c     calculate load/unload modulus
c
500   t=(s1-s3)/2.
      aa=1.00
      if(iconeps.ne.1)bb=1.00
      if(smean.lt.ap1) smean=ap1
      if(xn.gt.0.000001) aa=(smean/atmp)**xn
      if(iconeps.eq.1)go to 220
      if(xm.gt.0.000001) bb=(smean/atmp)**xm
220   if(t.ge.0.99*sm1) go to 600
      et=xku*aa*atmp+tt*tm1
      if(iconeps.ne.1)bt=xkb*atmp*bb
      go to  900
600   et=(xkl*aa*atmp+tt*tm1)*(1.0-rf*sr)**2
      if(iconeps.ne.1)bt=xkb*atmp*bb
900   continue
      btmax=17.0*et
      btmin=0.33*et

      if(iconeps.ne.1)then
      tbt=(alf1+alf3*dtt)*dtt*(1.+vide)*tm2
      btf=bt+tbt
      bt=btf
      endif

      if(bt.lt.btmin) bt=btmin
      if(bt.gt.btmax) bt=btmax
      if(iconeps.eq.1)go to 1100

1000  continue

1050  if(mt.eq.mtyp4c)goto 1100
      s=0.0
      t=0.0
      call shap4n(s,t,f,pfs,pft)                           ! Modification by NHV
      call thick4n(s,t,xe,ye,thick)
      call bmat4n(xe,ye,f,pfs,pft,b,detj,thick)

c     calculate incremental strains

      do 1300 i=1,4
      temp=0.0
      do 1200 j=1,8
1200  temp=temp+b(i,j)*disp(j)
1300  depi(i)=temp
      epsv=0.0
      do 1400 i=1,2
1400  epsv=epsv+depi(i)
  epsv=epsv+depi(4)

      ev=vide-(1.+vide)*epsv

      if(ev.lt.0.0)ev=vide*.01

1100  continue

      call perm(permws,xkw,coef,rw,tvisc,ev,vide,tt,pp)
```

: "et" keeps the good value until just before calling the subroutine "perm". Just after this subroutine it takes the value zero.
"et" isn't in any common block
This piece of code is part of a subroutine called by several different subroutines. What is even more strange is that when it is called in other parts of the code I doesn't have this problem ("et" keeps its value)
So if someone has ever met this kind of problem or have any idea about it I will be very gratefull

Comment: Your code shows 5 subroutine calls. Which one is causing the problem?

Comment: Does et show up in any common blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you have a memory access error, such as an array bounds violation, or a mismatch  between actual and dummy arguments.  Are the interfaces of the subroutines explicit, such as being "used" from a module?   Also try turning on compiler debugging options ... obviously subscript checking, but others might catch something.  An extensive set for gfortran 4.5 or 4.6 is:

-O2  -fimplicit-none  -Wall  -Wline-truncation  -Wcharacter-truncation  -Wsurprising  -Waliasing  -Wimplicit-interface  -Wunused-parameter  -fwhole-file  -fcheck=all  -std=f2008  -pedantic  -fbacktrace

Subscript checking is included in fcheck=all

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used the gfortran option -fbounds-check and found some strange dimension definitions in another subroutine. I fixed it and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. In my main program, I was using double precision but the numbers I calculated with in my subroutine were single precision. After I changed them to double it fixed the problem and I got actual values instead of 0.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. Yes, what you describe can indeed happen. Current compilers are often able to diagnose it using warning flags like those shown in the accepted answer bit it is best to always use modules. Be aware that this is a very old question and we now usually want more details in the questions so that answers use no guessing but can actually point out the actual problem.